# Multiple ternary values in simple without reactjs keys

Tags: javascript, if-statement, reactjs

I want to have two links optional displayed in case the user is logged in or not. So I came up with this which works but prompts an error:

```
var loginButton;
if (isLoggedIn) {
  loginButton = [
    <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/user">{msg.me}</Link></li>,
    <li><a href="/" onClick={onLogout}>{msg.logout}</a></li>
];
} else {
  loginButton = <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/login">{msg.login}</Link></li>;
}
```

The error is: `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of`Header`. See https://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.`

I could avoid this with the their given methods to create a class etc. But this seems quite expansive. Isn't their a way to achieve this easier for the reason that it is no loop or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Just put any key such as '1' or '2' as key attribute. There are not any other way to do it.

Something like this:

`var loginButton;
if (isLoggedIn) {
  loginButton = [
    <li><Link key="user_link" activeClassName="active" to="/user">{msg.me}</Link></li>,
    <li><a href="/" onClick={onLogout}>{msg.logout}</a></li>
];
} else {
  loginButton = <li><Link key="login_link" activeClassName="active" to="/login">{msg.login}</Link></li>;
}`

Comment: hm, unfortunately it does not work for me - the error is still there